# Differential Equation for CDF

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-distributions, functional-equations

Consider the following differential equation

$$F(cx) = F(x) + x F'(x)$$

for  $c>1$.

1. Does this differential equation belong to a some well known class?
2. Is there a way to find all the solutions $F(\cdot)$ of this equation that are also cumulative distribution functions?
3. $F(x) = x^a$ for a properly chosen $a$ is a solution. Is it unique in the class of cumulative distribution functions?

Comment: Given that you have both $x$ and $cx$ as argument the ODE is rather similar to delay differential equations. Instead of delay or retardation there seems to be a future component to the equation as $c>1$.